# How dirac delta function can be used through integral

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Dirac delta function is a singular distribution. So, unlike regular distributions, it isn't defined by integration against test functions because test function multiplied by Dirac delta function is undefined at $0$.

As a distribution, it is expressed as $f\{g\}=g(0)$.

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}\delta(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= f(x)\delta(x)\biggr|_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\delta(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\delta(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

And I read about its property about derivative in [the above formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7DTI.jpg). Here, I have doubts, how it can be derived with partial derivative regardless of its non integrable?

Comment: I agree i think that this is not valid. The definition of the derivative of a distribution $T$ is (usually) defined by $DT(\varphi) = - T (D \varphi)$ (where $D$ is the derivative and $\varphi $ a test function). So if we abuse the notation and write distributions as if they were given by integration (which is common) then the first and last expression in the equation are equal (by definition). But the "partial integration" in between does not make sense. Or maybe the source has a different definition of derivative of a distribution?

Comment: I also agree that it is not mathematically stringent. Is it from a physics book? The definition of the derivative of a distribution is however based on integration by parts. Results for ordinary functions are often used to define operations on distributions.

Comment: @jd27 I think your comment should be an answer (unless there is some duplicate).

Comment: As **jd27** noted, the calculation described can be seen more as a conceptual motivation for defining the distribution $\delta'(x)$ than as a stringent argument.